# Aptana 3 and Git: switching branches code remains the same. I cannot try to add new features

Tags: git, git-branch, aptana3

I'm new to use of git and Aptana.

Reading something about git, I discover that I can create new branches. And I can do this with Aptana.

But I understood that if I create a new branch, I have a separate environment in which I can work without take care of the changes I make, as they are not applied to my main source code.

So I expect that if, in Aptana, I switch between branches, the files I open should be the ones of the specific branches.

So if I have the file "`A`" with "some content" in the `master` branch, if I create a new branch (call it "`testBranch`") and edit the file "`A`" writing into it "Some new content", if I switch back to the `master` branch and open the file `A` it should contain again "some content".
If I open the same file from the `testBranch`, instead I should find in it "Some new content".

Instead, using Aptana, I see the modified file also if I switch between branches.
But I think isn't this the way git's developers thought the tool.

I think that if I'm in the `master` branch file "`A`" should contain "some content", while if I switch to "`testBranch`" file "A" should contain "some new content".

Am I wrong? Is there something I misunderstanding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have modified a file, but not committed it, Aptana won't modify it when you are switching branches (ie checkout another branch).

But if you had already committed that file in your current branch (before switching), and the content doesn't vary, then it could be related to this bug: "[Git checkout from GUI (App Explorer) sometimes doesn't checkout branch](https://aptanastudio.tenderapp.com/discussions/problems/2599-git-checkout-from-gui-app-explorer-sometimes-doesnt-checkout-branch)".

Answer (score 0):

Having the same problem,i decided to create the branch and switch to it using bash(command prompt), then because i was heading nowhere with refreshing,and Aptana still not getting it. I decided to restart Aptana (close all instances of my project) and then on starting it up again   the new branch was available, but it the my working space was pointing to HEAD. went back to the command prompt and ran $git status, to see which branch i was in and its my new branch from my $git branch checkout  // instruction before the restart. Select the new Branch and your good to go.